# LazyRow rememberSnapFlingBehavior doesn't center an item when long snap

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using android compose lazyRow with rememberSnapFlingBehavior to center an item and when an item moving to center its size becomes twice with animation.
and here is my codes.

```
setContent {
            val listState = rememberLazyListState(Int.MAX_VALUE/2)
            val visibleItemCounts = remember {
                derivedStateOf { listState.layoutInfo.visibleItemsInfo.size }
            }
            val selectedItemIndex =
                remember { derivedStateOf { listState.firstVisibleItemIndex + visibleItemCounts.value / 2 } }
            LazyRow(
                state = listState,
                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(3.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(top = 20.dp)
                    .height(120.dp),
                flingBehavior = rememberSnapFlingBehavior(listState),
            ) {
                items(
                    count = Int.MAX_VALUE,
                    itemContent = { index ->
                        val size by animateIntAsState(
                            targetValue = if (index == selectedItemIndex.value) 100 else 50,
                            animationSpec = tween(easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing),
                        )
                        if (index == selectedItemIndex.value)
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
                        Image(
                            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.ic_launcher_background),
                            contentDescription = "",
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .size(size.dp)
                                .alpha(if (index == selectedItemIndex.value) 1f else 0.3f)
                        )
                        if (index == selectedItemIndex.value)
                            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(5.dp))
                    }
                )
            }
        }
```

it works well when short snap. but when long snap, the big size image is not centered. It is slightly offset towards the left or right from the center.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UT2UX.gif)

i want to make the item centered. how can i make it?
Do i have to customize the flingBehavior?